Martingale with Poisson Process
I came across the following exercise: Let $N$ be a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ and $\{Y_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence of positive i.i.d random variables satisfying $\mathbb{E}[Y_1] < \infty$. $Y$ is independent of $N$. Let $X_t = \sum_{n=1}^{N_t}Y_n$, and $Z_t = X_t - \mathbb{E}[Y_1]\lambda t$. Show that $Z_t$ is an $(\mathcal{F}^Z_t)$-martingale.
Definitionally, $Z$ is $(\mathcal{F}^Z_t)$-adapted. I'm just having trouble showing that $\forall t \in T,  \mathbb{E}[|Z_t|] < \infty$.
The solution that I have goes like this:
\begin{align*}
&(1) \quad \mathbb{E}[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s^X] &= X_s + \mathbb{E}[X_t - X_s] \\
&(2) &= X_s + \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\sum_{n=N_s}^{N_t}Y_n|\mathcal{F}_t]] \\
&(3) &= X_s + \mathbb{E}[\sum_{n=N_s}^{N_t}\mathbb{E}[Y_n|\mathcal{F}_t^N]] \\
&(4) &= X_s + \mathbb{E}[\sum_{n=N_s}^{N_t}\mathbb{E}[Y_n]] \\
&(5) &= X_s + \lambda(t-s)\mathbb{E}[Y_1]
\end{align*}
$\rightarrow \mathbb{E}[|Z_t|] \leq \mathbb{E}[X_t] + \lambda \mathbb{E}[Y_1]t = 2\lambda\mathbb{E}[Y_1]t < \infty$
I really don't understand the last few steps of this proof. I can get step 1 because of independent increments, and I can see how we get 2 (Although I'm not sure I understand why we do this). In step 3, I'm not sure how we make the switch from $\mathcal{F}_t$ to $\mathcal{F}_t^N$. Step 4 I get because of independence. And I don't follow step 5, how does this work? Even from step 5, I'm not sure how that gets to the inequality below. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Assume w.l.o.g. that $\mathbb E Y_i=1$.
I presume that $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the sigma-algebra generated only by the Poisson process (not using $Y$ values). Then step (2) is just law of the total expectation, and
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_t-X_s)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X_t-X_s\mid\mathcal F_t)]$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_t-X_s\mid\mathcal F_t)
=\mathbb{E}[ \sum_{i:\ T_i\in[s,t]} Y_i\mid \mathcal F_t)]=
\sum_{i:\ T_i\in[s,t]} 1=N_t-N_s
$$
since $Y$ and $N$ are independent and
where $T_i$ is the $i$-the event of the Poisson process $N$. Hence
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_t-X_s)=\mathbb{E}[N_t-N_s]=\lambda(t-s).
$$
